# MVC database views and Url problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question that I hope someone will know the answer to.
Some of my views are stored in a database and they don't follow the MVC routes, they allow full URLs like:

> localhost:3892/Categories/Category/Asset?categoryId=3&id=119

and this works fine, I capture it and handle it on my custom MvcHandler class. The problem is, I have a URL like this:

> localhost:3892/Categories/Category/Asset/Edit?categoryId=3&id=119

This just has an extra element to it (Edit) nothing else has changed but it doesn't even hit my custom MvcHandler and I would like to know if anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a catchall route which looked like this:

```
    // CatchAll route
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Catchall", // Route name
        "{*url}"
    ).RouteHandler = new CmsRouteHandler();
```

That allows my url to be as long as I require